# How to know if a select2 has options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I don't need to know if you have options selected, I just need to know if you have options available. In case I have one or more options, I want to manually add another option that is “all”. And by default it is selected.

I have seen that the following is used on the internet, but I have tried it and it always gives me 1. It does not matter if there are 2 options, 1 or none.

```
$('#myselect option').length == 0

$('#myselect').has('option').length == 0

var menu = getElementById("select_id");
if(menu.options.length) {
    // has children
} else {
    // empty
}

$("#myselect option").length > 0
```

Naturally I have changed the identifier for mine.

Would someone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

My code is this:

```
$("#terminal_bookings").select2({
            ajax: {
                url: '{{ route('get_search_terminals_booking', ['client' => $client]) }}' + data,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term,
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (response) {
                    return {
                        results: response
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            language: {
                inputTooShort: function () {
                    return '{{ trans('common.insert_chars') }}';
                }
            }
        });
```

But when I put

```
console.log($("#terminal_bookings > option").length);
```

return 1 ever, when I have 0 o 1 o 2 options.

Comment: I mean that when I make a console log of the codes that I have put, the result that appears on the screen is always 1

Comment: This is a good reason why we should always use `===` in place of `==`

Comment: My mistake.  I was thinking of `.is(..)` so `$("select").has("option")` will return all of the `select`s that have at least one option.

Comment: *When* exactly are you adding your console.log?  Is it before the ajax has completed?

Comment: No, I put the console.log to the end of the code.

Comment: Right, so "at the end of the code" will be *before* the ajax call in select2 has completed.  Try putting your code in a button event (with a button the page obviously) then, when your select2 has finished loading and all the options are there, click the button.

Comment: In the end I have modified my php. If data arrives add the all options at the beginning.

Thanks all!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#myselect > option").length` to check if there are any `options(children)`,

```
if ($("#cars > option").length) { } // from eg below
```

Then simply prepend the All option if `true` like

```
$("#cars").prepend($('<option>', {
    value: 'All',
    text: 'All'
}));
```

---

<kbd>Working Code</kbd>

```js
if ($("#cars > option").length) {
  // has children
  $("#cars").prepend($('<option>', {
    value: 'All',
    text: 'All'
  }));

} else {
  // empty
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Agustín Tamayo Quiñones If the answer helped, can you please upvote and accept? Thanks